# How to load win32com Excel worksheet to Pandas df?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client

excel_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
file_path = r"path to the file"
file_password = "file password"
workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(file_path, Password=file_password)
sheet = workbook.Sheets("sheet name")
```

Now I'd like to take the sheet variable and load it into a Pandas df. I was trying to accomplish it via saving the sheet to a separate file and then reading it from Pandas, but it seems to be over-complicating the issue, as the file is both password protected and in .xlsm format, so re-opening it directly from Pandas isn't straightforward.

How do I do it?

Comment: try the UsedRange property of the sheet ... that should bring back all the data. You might have to do extra work to construct the column names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UsedRange property of the sheet will return an array that encompasses all the cells in the worksheet that have data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.UsedRange())
```

With the column headers as the column number, and the index as the row number. Both zero-based.